# how can we change colour and font of specific tabs of wxnotebook in wxwidget?

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm using wxnotebook control in my frame and want to change the color and font of specific tab of notebook but it can't done.

when I use `SetBackground()` the color of all tabs are changed not a particular tab.
I want to work on particular/specific tab that I want to do.

Can I do any thing with pages associated with wx.notebook but not for tabs?
Can we work on specific tab as we want?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a page ( tab ) to a notebook, you do something like this:

```
myNotebook->AddPage( myPage1, "TabText1");
```

To change the background color of the text displayed in that **one** page

```
myPage1->SetBackgroundColour( wxBlue )
```