# How to change wxNotebook page label color?

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I am using WxWidgets as UI framework in my software.
I added a wxNotebook to my main frame. I would like the notebook labels to be highlighted when selected.

**For example under Visual Studio**:
[image]

**In my case there is no highlight. We can barely see that the Settings tab is selected**:
[image]

Code side it look like this:

```
    wxNotebook* noteBook = (wxNotebook*)wxWindow::FindWindowByName("ModifierPanelNoteBook", parent);

    {
        wxNotebookPage* page = new wxNotebookPage(noteBook, -1);
        noteBook->AddPage(page, L"Settings");
    }

    {
        wxNotebookPage* page = new wxNotebookPage(noteBook, -1);
        noteBook->AddPage(page, L"Import");
    }

    {
        wxNotebookPage* page = new wxNotebookPage(noteBook, -1);
        noteBook->AddPage(page, L"Edition");
    }
```

I found a similar question but it is quite old and unsolved:
[how can we change colour and font of specific tabs of wxnotebook in wxwidget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699669/how-can-we-change-colour-and-font-of-specific-tabs-of-wxnotebook-in-wxwidget)

Comment: check wxAUI and wxAuiNotebook. Also look at the auidemo sample.

Comment: Trying it thank you

Comment: I tried the aui samples. wxAuiNotebook pages too are not highlighted when selected

Comment: what wx version? What platform? You can create your own art provider for the AUI and use it. You can't do that in native control however.